# iCloud not receiving emails sent via PHP

Tags: php, icloud

I am trying to send an email to an address that is something@icloud.com via the mail function in PHP.

I know that this mail function works because if I add a BCC to a different email I can see that the recipient of the email is there. The emails are also received when sent to different recipients. But both iCloud emails that have been tried do not receive the email.

Is there a known issue with icloud accepting PHP emails? I have seen some things online with this known but not a great deal of information. It would be useful if someone could shed some light on this? And if there is a fix/workaround?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as it is working for all domains tried except icloud. It seems to be a problem with sending just to icloud.com email addresses

Comment: icloud has no idea you used PHP to generate the email. The email will appear to come from whatever mailserver PHP's mail() command sent the data to. Your PHP config will be able to tell you, hopefully. More likely the email is badly constructed, or comes from an untrusted source and thus has been classified as spam, or it looks like it's spoofing the sender, or perhaps its contents make it look like spam, or some combination of all those (and more). If you're lucky it might be in the junk mail folder of the icloud account.If you're unlucky Apple's servers might have just rejected it completely

Comment: @a.norman Please take the time to read the entirety of the answer on the linked question.

Comment: the answer is simple: do not spoof sender addresses.

Comment: You could try using the following PHP component https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1140